# Problems when trying to INSERT into MySQL in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, insert-into

I'm using variables to record information about website users, to observe their behaviour on my site. My code looks like this:

```
<?php
$pages_visited = "www.example.com, www.example.com/example.php, www.example.com/demo.php";
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "pages_visited");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "An error occurred when connecting to the database. Sorry.";
    }
mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO visit_data ('Pages')
VALUES ('$pages_visited')");
mysqli_close($con);
```

Though, when I visit my website, nothing happens, and no new rows are added in the table visit_data. Why is this happening?

Comment: Any errors in your php error log?

Comment: try `mysqli_error($con)`

Comment: Try `"INSERT INTO visit_data (Pages)`

Comment: yes quotes are there :|

Comment: Try with removing single quotes like hjpotter92 has mentioned. Also make sure you are including all the NOT NULL  fields from table in insert query with their values.

Comment: mysqli_error results in: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Pages) VALUES ('$pages_visited')' at line 1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your query:

```
INSERT INTO visit_data (`Pages`) VALUES('".$pages_visited."')
```

Actually you are using Single quote('Pages'),
check bellow code.
I have verified this code locally its running

```
    <?php
$pages_visited = "www.example.com, www.example.com/example.php, www.example.com/demo.php";
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "pages_visited");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "An error occurred when connecting to the database. Sorry.";
    }

$try = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO visit_data (`Pages`) VALUES('".$pages_visited."')");

if($try === false){
    echo 'error - ';
    echo mysqli_error($con);
}   else{
        echo 'all good';
    }

mysqli_close($con);
```

Answer (score 1):

try mysqli prepared statements(the error is not associated with not using prepared statements but I thought it would be better to use since mysql functions are deprecated)

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'database');
if ($db->connect_errno) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $db->connect_errno . ") " . $db->connect_error;
}

$pages_visited = "www.example.com, www.example.com/example.php, www.example.com/demo.php";

$stmt = $db->prepare("insert into `visit_data` (Pages) values(?)");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $pages_visited);
$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score -1):

You gotta use '". $text_var . "' when using strings. Make sure that the table column your using is correct and that your not leaving out any columns that don't accept a null value unless you used default on table creation.

this should work

```
<?php

$pages_visited = "www.example.com, www.example.com/example.php, www.example.com/demo.php";
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "pages_visited");

if ( mysqli_connect_errno() )
{
    echo "An error occurred when connecting to the database. Sorry.";
}

mysqli_query( $con, "INSERT INTO visit_data ( Pages ) VALUES ( '" . $pages_visited . "' )" );

mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: This is susceptible to sql injection.  A prepared statement with data binding would be a much better solution.  Also, you included the quotes (') are 'Pages' that are causing the error.  They should be back ticks (`): `Pages`

Comment: Thank you! Replacing the single quotes with the tick fixed the problem.

Comment: explain how it is if the inserted data is hard coded, and yeah I was in a clan meeting trying to do a signature in photoshop. I was multitasking my bad.

Comment: @user3587554 Yeah, I'm sure he just wants to store a list of example.com URLs in a database  :)

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. The sample code is hardcoded, correct? How is it open to sql injection then if the data being stored is a constant? Remember it's based off the posted code not what he does futurewise.